# Pip install creates a true directory

Tags: pip

When I install a package (say `transformers`) pip creates a directory named true
Original directory tree:

```
└─┬ .       
  ├── .env/  
  └── .vscode/
```

after `pip install transformers`

```
└─┬ .       
  ├── .env/
  ├── true/
  └── .vscode/
```

[image: inside true]

Comment: Not for me. Most probably something in your local environment, Please describe the environment (OS, IDE, Python version) and show exact commands beyond `pip install`. Virtualenv?

Comment: On any pip install. Ubuntu 21.04. no virtual environment

Comment: What's the content of the directory? `ls -lR true` ?

Comment: I am guessing pip's cache for something

Comment: Yes, it's a [pip cache](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/) but I never saw it in directory `true`. It must be `~/.pip/cache/`

Comment: pip config change fixed the problem- do not set `cache-dir` to `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not change `global.cache-dir` option. It takes paths only and does not take booleans. (so if you do not want to have a pip cache, do not set it to false using `pip config set global.cache-dir false`) as false or any other value is treated as a folder path and it defaults to being relative.

Comment: is there a global option to disable caching

Comment: I think there is (this is what I was trying to do) but may not work properly